# Shake for a certain period of time?

Tags: ios, swift, alarm, shake

I would like to use the shake function to turn off an alarm clock, which would cause the user to shake the phone for 30 seconds.  Is there a way to test for how long the user has been shaking the device as well as how would I set up the shake function?

I only understand swift code by the way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
var timer = Timer()

override func motionBegan(_ motion: UIEvent.EventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if motion == .motionShake {
        print("Device shaken, shake timer started")
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 30, target: self, selector: #selector(turnOffAlarm), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
}

override func motionEnded(_ motion: UIEvent.EventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if motion == .motionShake {
        print("Device shake stop, shake timer stopeed")
        timer.invalidate()
    }
}

@objc func turnOffAlarm() {
    print("Alarm off")
    timer.invalidate()
}
```

When the user starts shaking the phone you start your timer with a 30 second interval, if the user stop shaking you will call invalidate otherwise after 30 seconds you will call turnOffAlarm and invaldiate the timer.

Comment: This doesn't stop the timer if the user stops shaking within the time period

Comment: @RudolfJ, you´re right. Updated the answer with the `motionEnded` function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you can attach a timer to shake gestures, but perhaps you could just set a counter to watch how many times it got triggered?

To catch a shake gesture, just add this method to your view controller:

```
override func motionBegan(motion: UIEventSubtype, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    if motion == .MotionShake {
        print("Device was shaken!")
    }
}
```